# Implementing stack ADT in C++

Tags: c++, stack

I'm fairly new to C++ and thus trying to implement at stack ADT from my knowledge of  Java. Here's my header file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

template <class S>

class stack{

public:
  Stack(const int): size_(size), top(-1){
    if(size_>0){
      this->size_ = size;
    }else{
      std::cout<<"Stack can be initialized by values greater than 0"<< std::endl;

    }
    this->top = -1;
    stack_pointer = new S[this->size_];
  };

  Stack(const stack& S): size_(S.size_), top_(S.top_){

    if(this == &S){
      return *this;
    }

      stack_pointer = new S[S.size_];
      for(int i=0; i< size_; i++){
        stack_pointer[i] = S[i];
      }
      this->top = stack_pointer[S.top_];
      delete[] S;

}

  ~Stack(){
    delete[] stack_pointer;
  }


private:
  int size_;
  int top_;
  S* stack_pointer;



};
```

And here's the cpp

```
#include "stack.hpp"

template<typename S>

bool Stack<S>::push(const S& data){
  if(this->top_ >= size-1)
      resize();
  stack_pointer[++top_]= data;

}
void Stack<S>::resize(){
  temp = new S[this->size];
  for(int i=0; i< size_; i++){
      temp[i] = stack_pointer[i];
  }
  delete[] stack_pointer;
  size_ = size_*2;


  stack_pointer = new stack_pointer[size_];
  for(int j=0; j < size_/2; j++){
    stack_pointer[i] = temp[i];
  }

  delete[] temp;


}

bool Stack<S>::pop(){
  if(top>0){
    return stack_pointer[top--];
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}

bool Stack<S>::peek(){
  if(top>0){
    top--;
  }
}
```

My question is, is this the most optimal way to do stack implementation in C++ or are their more efficient ways to do the same. Also does this class need any sort of operator overloading?

Comment: This doesn't compile. It should be working before you worry about how fast it's working.

Comment: In your dtor `delete stack_pointer;` should be `delete [] stack_pointer;`

Comment: exceptional C++ (http://www.amazon.co.uk/Exceptional-C-Herb-Sutter/dp/0201615622) has a great example of how to implement a Stack with a very deep discussion on exception safety. But it may be difficult for a newbie in C++

Comment: I believe that linked list is more appropriate than dynamically allocated array .

Comment: `return stack_pointer[top--];` when returning `bool` is rather unfortunate. This means that you'll test it with `int` (because that's everyone's default choice) and it will compile, but then you'll use it with your own class, or something else that isn't convertible to `bool`, and it will no longer compile.

Comment: @user3613500, FWIW, the standard stack class is based on `std::deque`, which is neither a vector, nor a linked list.

Comment: Incorporated edits as suggested. Working on getting it to compile it. Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: You should learn more about C++ standard [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) then use them.